# grepl in R: spurious match despite intra-word dash

Tags: r, grepl

below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
v=c("\\<skill-saw\\>","\\<saw blade\\>")
text="xx placed his hand beneath skill-saw blade"
sapply(v,grepl,text)
```

The last command returns c(TRUE,TRUE) where I was expecting c(TRUE,FALSE). Any idea on how to achieve that? The idea is that the keyword "skill-saw" should be detected as present in the text, but not the keyword "saw blade"...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: From `?regex`, " (The interpretation of ‘word’ depends on the locale and implementation: these are all extensions.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `regex` lookbehind

```
v <- c('(?<= )\\bskill-saw\\b', '(?<= )\\bsaw blade\\b')
 unname(sapply(v, grepl, text, perl=TRUE))
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

#### Update

Based on the new "text", may be

```
text1 <- "xx placed his hand beneath skill saw-blade"

v <- c('(?<= )\\bskill-saw\\b', '(?<= )\\bsaw-?blade\\b')
unname(sapply(v, grepl, text1, perl=TRUE))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In order to anticipate future issues, how would you combine a lookbehind with a lookahead? For instance, in: text="xx placed his hand beneath skill saw-blade", unname(sapply(v, grepl, text, perl=TRUE)) should return c(FALSE,TRUE) this time, (with v made of skill saw and saw-blade)

Comment: sorry, your solution only works because you kept the intra-word dash in skill saw. What I was asking for was c(FALSE,TRUE) returned by unname(sapply(v, grepl, text, perl=TRUE)) with "skill saw" and "saw-blade". As I said, I am trying to anticipate future problematic cases and wonders whether it is possible to combine a lookbehind with a lookahead in the unique statement (which would work for both texts). I tried: c('(?<= )\\...\\b(?=)', '(?<= )\\...\\b(?=)') but this does not work.

Comment: @user2835597 These word combinations may be a bit difficult to achieve within the framework of regex.  Or else you need to have some key table of all those split-words and then do the matching.